# Make a VBA form appear in windows task bar

Tags: vba, windows, office365

I am programming a little application (an overgrown macro really) in Visual Basic for Applications in Office 365. What it does is:

1. Displays one window that has a few input fields.
2. Once I fill out those fields with data I can press a button on the form and a summary in a nice graphical form is displayed in a second window (a second form is displayed using `UserForm2.show`).
3. The second user form can be updated with new data by typing in updated text in first form and updating the second form by pressing a button on the first form (in the form of `UserForm2.TextField1.Text = UserForm1.Label1.Text`.

Both forms are modeless so the user can work in Outlook whilst the forms are running.

All works fine except one caveat:

Both forms are not visible on the Windows Taskbar, in the Task Manager, but most importantly they are not visible as separate windows to teleconferencing software we are using. And this is the macro's sole purpose.

**Question**: Is it possible to make the entire macro (or just `UserForm2`) run as if it was a separate application, so it appears in the Task Bar as a separate window, and not an internal form running inside Outlook?

The idea is not to run it independently of Outlook (or Excel), but to make them visible to external programs.

I tried a few options available on the Internet, but none of them work, and honestly I do not know where to begin, or how to circumvent it if it is not possible to do directly within the available API. Can you advise?

Comment: I doubt that is possible. But if you created an application using Visual Studio instead it would be simple. Those apps can talk to Excel and Outlook easily.

Comment: @braX Well Visual Studio is not available. But, I have seen a similar setup (a macro running in Outlook) that was showing as an independent icon on the Task Bar in Windows. Probably a hack, but IMHO it can be done.

Comment: Well Visual Studio is free... but OK, good luck...

Comment: I agree with @braX. Everything to do with VBA is *hosted* inside its parent application. The parent application is registered with Windows as an application. It's not possible to do that with VBA components. My best guess at what you saw would be a separate instance of Outlook (assuming this really was an Outlook macro and not something else that macro called or an add-in).